# CodeDeploy doesnt deploy to new autoscailing instance

Tags: autoscaling, aws-code-deploy

I have an autoscailing group, this creates an instance that installs the codedeploy agent.

I then have an codedeploy config setup to work with AutoScailing and the ELB for health checks.

For some reason when a new instance is created by autoscailing, codedeploy doesnt initiate a deployment on the new instance. As far as im aware when using autoscailing and linked to code deploy it should just deploy the code any time a new instance is built?

Any ideas what could be causing this or id there are any logs i can provide to help?

also note that i use codepipeline to initiate codedeploy when the codecommit is updated with any updated code. not sure if this makes a difference.

Comment: We once had a problem that a codedeploy was canceled as the codedeploy app was updating at the same time. So I would check the logs...

Comment: Are you sure your autoscalingroup is attached to the codedeploy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so after leaving the autoscailing group for a few days it eventually started deploying as expected. Not sure why it took so long to settle down though!

Comment: I had some cases when it took long to execute but never a day. Strange.

Answer (score 0):

CodeDeploy initiates a deployment to a newly spun up instance only when there is a previous successfully deployed revision to the deployment group. You need to make sure that you were able to successfully deploy a revisin to the codedeploy deployment group which the autoscaling group is part of to ensure the hook is established.